# How do I interpret this Residuals Plot?

Tags: regression, scikit-learn, residuals

I have some data where the histogram shows insurance premiums normally distributed except for a "spike" at the upper bound. (x-axis = price, y-axis = n_observations)

[image]

I am visualising the results of a Random Forrest Regression as follows

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from yellowbrick.datasets import load_concrete
from yellowbrick.regressor import ResidualsPlot

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

#df = df[df['INSURER3_PREMIUM'] < 380]

#Linear Regression
X = df[df.columns[:-1]]
y = df[df.columns[-1:]].values.ravel()

# Create the train and test data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


# Instantiate the linear model and visualizer
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=15, min_samples_leaf=5, n_jobs=-1, random_state=0) 
visualizer = ResidualsPlot(model, size=(1080, 720))

visualizer.fit(X_train, y_train)  # Fit the training data to the visualizer
visualizer.score(X_test, y_test)  # Evaluate the model on the test data
visualizer.show()
```

Result is ...

[image]

I then remove the "spike" in the histogram by uncommenting the line

```
#df = df[df['INSURER3_PREMIUM'] < 380]
```

and re-running the code. The result is ...

[image]

I am struggling to understand how to interpret these results. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you separately model only the premiums *greater than* 380?

Comment: the residuals are all 0 because all training labels are the same (386.363985)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly are you confused about? The straight line in the residuals? That comes from the observations you have at 386.363985, I believe.

The true value is this constant for all of the predictions on the line, but the model predicts different values for them. Since the outcome is always the same, the form of the residuals will be 
$$y = x - y_{true} = x - c$$ 
where x is the model prediction, and $y_{true} = c = 386.363985$. So it's a straight line, just as you see. For example, at x = 250, $y = 250 - 386.36 \approx -136$, which is the value on the plot. In your second plot, you remove the values at around 386, so the straight line disappears.

Incidentally, you have a second straight line at 200, where things go the other way: the model predicts values greater than 200 and the true value is exactly 200.

Does this answer your question, or was there something else that was confusing you?

Comment: Is there any explanation for why the predictions for those 386.3 reach about double the error for the rest of the data

Comment: I am trying to understand the impact on the model of all those 386.3 observations. Clearly they skew the distribution of the residuals for example. Would an experienced data scientist ever remove most of those observations in order to return the distribution of the observations to a more Normal shape and improve the model?